# Is there a way to build exceptions into my search and replace code?

Tags: python

I need to strip underscores out of filenames, but not ALL underscores.

**Original file:** "Bob's_House_RZ.png", "Jim_and_Judy's_House_RR.png"

**Desired result:** "Bob's House_RZ.png", "Jim and Judy's_House_RR.png"

I've written some code to replace characters, but I'm wondering how I can add exceptions for certain patterns, like "_RR" and "_RZ" above.  Since I'm new to programming, I'm wondering what the best practice is.  Thanks for any help.

```
import os

target_dir = r"C:\Somefolder\\"

old_string = "_"
new_string = " "

extension = ".png"
count = 0


for file in os.listdir(target_dir):
    if file.endswith(extension):
        if file.find(old_string) > 0:
            count += 1
            os.rename(target_dir + "\\" + file, target_dir + "\\" + file.replace(old_string, new_string))
```

Comment: `"Jim and Judy's_House_RR.png"` - it appears that you also indend to exclude `House` ?

Comment: Actually a typo, but "_House" could serve as another example of something I'd like to keep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With short regex pattern:

```
import re

extension = ".png"

# for demonstration purpose
files = ["Bob's_House_RZ.png", "Jim_and_Judy's_House_RR.png"]
pat = re.compile(r'_(?!(R[RZ]\b))')

for f in files:
    if f.endswith(extension):
        new_fname = pat.sub(' ', f)
        print(new_fname)
        # do the renaming logic
```

The output:

```
Bob's House_RZ.png
Jim and Judy's House_RR.png
```

Comment: I'm reverse engineering your example to learn regex, thanks very much!

Comment: `# target_dir = r"C:\Somefolder\\"

extension = ".png"

pattern = re.compile(r'_(?=[A-Za-z][a-z])')

for x in os.listdir(target_dir):
    if x.endswith(extension):
        new_name = pattern.sub(' ', x)
        os.rename(target_dir + "\\" + x, target_dir + "\\" + new_name)`

Answer (score 0):

Usually when you are trying to locate patterns in strings a RegEx function is a solid go to in many languages. You can read more about it [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_regex.asp)